# What should i replace YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS and YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_PATH for login with facebook in flutter?

Tags: flutter, facebook-graph-api, flutter-layout, facebook-login, flutter-dependencies

i am trying to include login with facebook feature in flutter application. Going through the steps, i did generated key hash for debug mode. However, i'm not being able to figure out what to replace the above two values in  **keytool -exportcert -alias YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS -keystore YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_PATH | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64**  for generating release key hash. What should i do?

Answer (score -1):

You may find these info in the file: **android/key.properties**

Release key alias is any alias you want, remember that as you'll need them for updates. Path is the path where you want the key to be generated.